# OpenCV: cant get framerate from video

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to get framerate for video but I always get -nan on linux.

```
VideoCapture video(input);
if (!video.isOpened())  // zakoncz program w przypadku, problemu z otwarciem
{
    exit(0);
}

double fps = video.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
```

My openCv version is 2.4.7. The same code works fine on windows.

Comment: This worked for me on Linux with opencv 2.4.7. Which Ffmpeg version have you installed ? Try to compile lastest version.

Comment: I have same problem, I have installed last version of all packages but returns `nan` on unix whixh properly works on mac.

Comment: Same issue when I updated it to 2.4.8. It was working fine when it was 2.4.5.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that it's camera dependent. Some (API) functions are sometimes not implemented in OpenCV and/or supported by your camera. Best would be if you check the code on github.

Concerning your problem: I am able to get the frame rates with a normal webcam and a XIMEA camera with your code.

Tested on:

- Ubuntu 15.04 64bit
- OpenCV 3.0.0 compiled with Qt and XIMEA camera support

You could measure your frame rate yourself:

```
double t1 = (double)cv::getTickCount();
// do something
t1 = ((double)cv::getTickCount() - t1)/cv::getTickFrequency();
```

Gives you the time that `//do something` spent.

Answer (score 1):

It is from a file, you can try to estimate it yourself.

```
VideoCapture video("name_of_video.format");
int frameCount = (int)video.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT) ;
//some times frame count is wrong, so you can verify
video.set(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES , frameCount-1);

//try to read the last frame, if not decrement frame count
    while(!(video.read(nextFrame))){

    frameCount--;

    video.set(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES , frameCount-1);
}

//it is already set above, but just for clarity
      video.set(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES , frameCount-1);
      double fps = (double)(1000*frameCount)/( video.get(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC));
      cout << "fps: " << fps << endl;
```

This is how I get framerate when using CV_CAP_PROP_FPS fails

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't clarify if this refers to video from a live source (webcam) or from a video file.

If the latter, the capabilities of OpenCV will depend on the format and codecs used in the file. For some file formats, expect to get a 0 or NaN.

If the former, the real fps of the source may not be returned, especially if the requested framerate is not supported by the hardware, and a different one is used instead. For this case I would suggest an approach similar to @holzkohlengrill's, but only do that calculation after an initial delay of say 300ms (YMMV), as grabbing of the first frames and some initialisations happening can mess with that calculation.